# making slingscold my default dash home/search engine

Tags: launcher

I have recently installed slingscold, an app launcher that navigates your applications. and now, I want to make it my default dash so that when I press the `super` key, I will get slingscold instead of the default dash home. Thanks :) here is a screenshot of it
[image]

Comment: Hold on, The two are distinctly different...  You want to replace the upper-left icon with that of `slingscold` **and** you want the super key bound to `slingscold` as well, right?  Well in that case, you need to ensure that slingscold is a window manager as to do the first one, you need to remove unity to be able to put another icon there...  It's hard-coded...  The second one needs Unity removed too!  **:-(**

Comment: having slingscold come up on super key is good enough for me

Comment: Unfortunately (In the mean time I went looking through the source code) it's not a windows Manager, just an application so you cannot disable Unity, so you cannot bind it to super key, nor to the icon in the top left corner without re-programming Unity...  (Sorry, too much work for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At the time of this writing, no solution existed, but [there is one here now!](https://askubuntu.com/a/625112/344926)**

*Original answer for historical reasons:*

Unfortunately (In the mean time I went looking through the source code) SlingScold is not a Window Manager, just an application... So you cannot disable Unity, so you cannot bind it to super key, nor to the icon in the top left corner without re-programming Unity...

So what you want cannot be done...

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.  **:-(**

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 5):

All this requires is the **Unity Tweak Tool**. Merely navigate to **Unity > Additional**. Where it says "Show the launcher -- Super" Change the binding to backspace. That will disable the Window's key binding to the launcher.

You can use many methods to bind Slingscold to the Super key. I used **System Settings** **Keyboard > Shortcuts** and the "+" button to create a custom shortcut. The command to run "slingscold" is simply `slingscold`.